# how to get email address of logged in user on window phone 8

Tags: email, windows-phone-8

how to get email address of logged in user on window phone 8 using Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Account.

Comment: No API support avilable

Answer (score 1):

If by "logged in user" I assume you're referring to the main Live ID account on the phone, then you won't be able to get that specific mail account, as there is no way to do this with the current Windows Phone SDK.